# Update Null Fields with SQL in MS Access

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, ms-access-2003

I'm trying to run some SQL commands in Access VBA to update the blank (null) fields in a column with the value obtained from a combobox in the form.

At the moment I'm receiving

> Run time Error '3061' Too Few Parameters. Expected 1

but it appears to be properly formed.

The code I'm using is below. User will be passed as a string, e.g. - "Joe Bloggs".

```
Public Sub testSub(user as string)
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim sqlstr as String
set db as CurrentDB

sqlstr = "UPDATE tTable1 SET Field1 = [" & user & "] WHERE Field1 IS NULL;"

db.Execute sqlstr

End Sub
```

Comment: Why those square brackets? Doesn't that imply a column name in this case?

Comment: Take care for `Jim O'Shea`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to have user as a `'string'` in your query using single quotes. Also, I have always used `set db = currentdb` instead of using `as`

```
Public Sub testSub(user as string)
Dim db as DAO.Database
Dim sqlstr as String
set db = CurrentDB

sqlstr = "UPDATE tTable1 SET Field1 = '" & user & "' WHERE Field1 IS NULL;"

db.Execute sqlstr

End Sub
```

> EDIT:
>   As @jarlh has mentioned I agree, I don't think that the square parentheses are required

Answer (score 3):

Consider a parameter query instead of concatenating a quoted string value into your `UPDATE` statement text.  You don't need those quotes when using the parameter approach, and that also safeguards you from the [issue Alex warned about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36453949/update-null-fields-with-sql-in-ms-access#comment60520958_36453949) (when the user string itself contains an apostrophe).

```vb
Public Sub testSub(ByVal pUser As String)
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim qdf As DAO.QueryDef
    Dim sqlstr As String

    sqlstr = "UPDATE tTable1 SET Field1 = [which_user] WHERE Field1 IS NULL;"
    Set db = CurrentDb
    Set qdf = db.CreateQueryDef(vbNullString, sqlstr)
    qdf.Parameters("which_user").Value = pUser
    qdf.Execute sqlstr, dbFailOnError
End Sub
```